# The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.0

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to build [aspnet\mvc](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc) and I'm receiving the following error after running `build.cmd /t:Restore` from the cmd line per the [instructions here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc#building-from-source).

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.0.  Either target .NET Core 1.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.0.

According to `dotnet --info` I have the 2.0.2.  Is that not a high enough version?

[image: dotnet sdk version screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install the SDK or just the runtime version of .net core 2.0? Also did you install the plugin for Visual Studio?

Comment: I probably clicked the 'Get .Net Core 2.0' from the File -> New Project dialog.  I would assume that installs the SDK.  Based upon `dotnet --info` I have version 2.0.2 of the SDK installed, no? @DanielGale

Comment: 'did you install the plugin' which plugin? @DanielGale

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core
The Visual Studio Tools

Comment: Check if you have a `global.json` somewhere to force using old SDK. Remove that file, or update the version number inside so use the 2.x SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking your `global.json` file in the root of the project/solution.
I had the same problem when opened a old .NET Core project and tried to compile it in multi-target mode for both .NET Standard 1.6 and 2.0.

```
{ 
  "projects": ["src", "tests"], 
  "sdk": { 
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  } 
}
```

Since I had .MET Core SDK 2.0.3 installed I just changed the version property to

```
"version": "2.0.3"
```

You might also remove `global.json` file completely, since it considered deprecated after [.NET 1.0 => 1.1 migration](http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/01/19/project-json-to-csproj/#dotnet-migrate) and project.json / runtimeconfig.json / global.json / hosting.json / .. infrastructure being dropped in favor of `.csproj` format.

You can try replacing it with

```
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```

for every project.

However some people suggest avoid using **both** `global.json` and `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` for painless .NET Core SDK/Runtime updates.